# Why does this request not POST?

Tags: go, post

There are many similar questions implemented in different stacks, but I have not found a useful answer.  This code is modeled on many different tutorials, here is one: https://divyanshushekhar.com/golang-forms-data-request-body/

Pressing the button is supposed to submit the form so that the value of dataRequest can be used, however, it does not appear to post.  Why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src * 'self' data: https:">
<head>
  <title>Demo</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./favicon.ico">
</head>

<body style="background-color:#F0F8FF" style="font-size: 18px; font-family:verdana,arial,tahoma,serif;">

<form name="demoForm" style="background-color:#92a8d1">
  <fieldset> 
    <input id="dataRequest" type="request" method="POST" value=""/>
    <button type="submit" value="Run" />
  </fieldset>
</form> 


</body>
</html>
```

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "log"
)


func index() http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        switch r.Method {
        case "GET":     
            http.ServeFile(w, r, "visible/index.html")
            return 
        case "POST":
            fmt.Println("Posted a request!")
            err := r.ParseForm(); 
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            request := r.Form.Get("dataRequest")
            fmt.Println(request)
            return
        }
    })
}



func main() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.Handle("/", index())
    http.ListenAndServeTLS(":443", "./server.crt", "./server.key", mux)
}
```

Comment: You put the method attribute on the input element. It should be on the form element instead. And the id attribute on the input element should be "name" instead.

Comment: You saved my life!  Now I can stop banging my head against the wall. If you would put your answer into its own window, I will be happy to accept it :)